# can you change css background size proerty based on the size of image?

Tags: html, css, image

i want to display several different photos with different ratios and sizes. if the image is big enough i'm displaying it as `background-size: cover;` or else if it's not big enough i'd like to use `background-size: cover; background-position: center;` and i'd like to display the image blurred on the two sides of the sharp image.

I know that it's possible. My question is that can it be done with using CSS only?

I have the javascript solution already but would be nicer to have it with pure css.

Comment: share the JS solution so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve